# Oracle DB as file storage

Tags: oracle, artifactory

We think about migrating our artifactory from disk filestorage to store all the aritfacts as blobs in Oracle DB
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Oracle
Unfortunately, there's not much info about such practice. So my question did anyone do it? My main concern is regarding performance. Is it as fast as local filestorage?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's possible to use the Database for full metadata and binary storage in Artifactory, but this is not recommended.

From [best practices for managing your artifactory filestore](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-for-managing-your-artifactory-filestore/):

> 4. DATABASE
>
> By default, Artifactory separates the binaries from their metadata.
> Binaries are stored in the filestore and their metadata is stored in a
> database. While it’s possible to store the binaries in the database as a
> BLOB, it is not recommended because databases have limitations when
> storing large files and this can lead to performance degradation and
> negatively impact operational costs.

So it's not recommended. Database is usually slower than file or object storage.

Your best bet is to simply test it and see if it meets your required KPIs.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I guess that answers my question, so it's better to use another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to store binary files within an Oracle DB, but it's not something I'd recommend doing for a massive amount of files.

A much better practice is to store the files within storage and use the database for the file paths.

The reason why I wouldn't recommend using Oracle is because of the retrieval speeds. You will put strain on the Database and it might end up slowing down slightly or even significantly.

The most I'd save on a database are single files directly linked to an entry, which are not often retrieved. Such as documentation in a .pdf file.

Comment: Thank you, that what I was thinking myself. So I guess we'll have to use another solution.  Thanks.